# PL SQL Code **ORACLE **

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apps

I wonder if this code can work? what I try to do is update a field from the record. The new variable is `:newNote` which will comie from an input from the user, `TEXT` is the field name. `OBJID` and `OBJVERSION` are the unique value for the API. If somebody can tell if this code will work I will appreciate.

```
DECLARE
   info_         VARCHAR2 (4000) := NULL;
   OBJID_        VARCHAR2 (4000) := :Project__OBJECTID;
   OBJVERSION_   VARCHAR2 (4000) := :Project__OBJECT;
   ATTR_         VARCHAR2 (4000) := NULL;
   newNote_      VARCHAR2 (2000) := :newNote;
BEGIN
   CLIENT_SYS.CLEAR_ATTR (ATTR_);
   CLIENT_SYS.ADD_TO_ATTR ('TEXT', newNote_, ATTR_);
   ENG_PART_REV_JOURNAL_API.MODIFY__ (info_,
                                      OBJID_,
                                      OBJVERSION_,
                                      ATTR_,
                                      'DO');
END;
```

Comment: I wonder if this code can work?

Comment: what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I wonder if this code can work? what I try to do is update a field from the record. The new variable is :newNote which will coming from an input from the user, TEXT is the field name. OBJID and OBJVERSION are the unique value for the API. IF somebody can tell if this code will work I will appreciate.

Comment: Why don't you simply try it? You're calling different procedures and we (OK, to be honest, *I*) have no idea what they do (apart from reading their names so they probably *clear attributes*, *add attribute* and *modify* something), but - will that work? How could I know?

Comment: @Littlefoot - I think CLIENT_SYS is an E-Business Suite built-in. But basically, yes, an ounce of *do* is worth a ton of *speculation*.

Comment: Aha; I know that EBS exists and that's all; thank you, @APC.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using this:

```
DECLARE
info_ varchar2(4000) := NULL;
OBJID_ varchar2(4000) := :Project__OBJECTID;
OBJVERSION_ varchar2(4000) := :Project__OBJECT;
ATTR_ varchar2(4000) := 'TEXT'||chr(31)||:newNote||chr(30);
newNote_ varchar2(2000) := :newNote;

BEGIN

ENG_PART_REV_JOURNAL_API.MODIFY__(info_ ,OBJID_,OBJVERSION_,ATTR_,'DO');

end;
```